# Where do Google Maps/Bing Maps get their satellite imagery from?

Tags: image, google-maps

1.i just wanted to  know that from where google and bing got the complete earth images or satellite imaginary?

2.is it possible to get data like that for a individual person?

i found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204644/how-does-google-maps-work) about google maps working at stackoverflow but it doesn't answer my question.

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia:thanks for editing and sorry for my grammatical error

Comment: No problem, hopefully more people answer your question now. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google, Yahoo!, Microsoft, Michelin, Yandex and a lot others bought their data from various providers. They are usually named on the specific map and there isn't only one provider.

[image]

or

[image]

If you want free to use map data you can take a look at http://www.openstreetmap.org/ .

If you want free *satellite* map data then it's more complicated. This looks promising: http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/ .

Answer (score 2):

The company [GeoEye, in Mission KS](http://www.geoeye.com/CorpSite/) has launched a satelite called [GeoEye-1](http://www.geoeye.com/CorpSite/products/imagery-sources/Default.aspx#geoeye1) which is used to produce the high qualitiy images which are used for the [google maps](http://earth.google.com/geoeye/index.html#utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=ha&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk-geoeye&utm_term=geoeye).

Comment: It appears that the GeoEye link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

*1.i just wanted to know that from where google and bing got the complete earth images or
satellite imaginary?*

Look at the bottom, right-hand corner of Google Maps.

*2.is it possible to get data like that for a individual person?*

Take a look at **[Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/)**