# how does the google maps identifies the roads(paths)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

when i went through the source code of the google maps page i've realized that the whole map is formed by small tiles of images. But how does the javascript identifies the roads on the google maps to show the way from ourlocation to destination??

Comment: Possible source of info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204644/how-does-google-maps-work

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't tell you HOW it works, it is a very complex application but all the work is done on the server and the reason the page shows the map as images is purely down to the limited ways in which a browser can display content.

Answer (score 0):

Google have several layers with information about streets, roads, etc... when you use google maps only show a "graphical representation" of their data in bitmap format, but they need a "vectorial" layer that we don't see it.

Calculate routing is a very complex infraestructure problem in GIS server, for example, with Geoserver and PostGIS you can use Dijkstra Routing with Pgdijkstra.

It's very complex question, for a short answer.

Comment: Ok, let me make it more specific. are there any JavaScript apis to identify the color of an image at a given point?