# Google maps loading images like

Tags: javascript, image, load, maps

I started to create a script that allows me to split a big image into small pieces,to zoom, drag , etc.

I want to know what are the possibilities to load the small images just in the active area like in Google Maps (visible). I thought to try to determine the approximate location of one element with some calcules and to determine the element with document.elementFromPoint, but it's not a cross browser solution.

Another solution could be: loading from the beginning just the images from active area and when the user drag or zoom the script must calculate the elements that are new in active area.

see here what I mean active and inactive area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRY5K.jpg

PS: I searched the entire site but I did not found an answer. I read also this topic : [How does Google Maps work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204644/how-does-google-maps-work) , but I would like to develop myself the script. (I don't need the complexity of Google Maps, just few features)

Comment: Yahoo has an image loader (YUI) which is an easy to use API for determining when to load images asynchronously. So, you can predicatively load images to make your zoom in smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Its an opensource project that does exactly what you want.  Its written for .net... but i think it might be what your looking for

DeepZoom is created by SeaDragon and is built for silverlight but they also have a Javascript implementation too called [SeaDragon Ajax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/gg413360.aspx)

Comment: @ Evan: The DeepZoom script uses Silverlight, I do not want this. I want a solution for my scrit: how to detect images from active (zoomed or dragged) area

Comment: Well you probably already know this but I would recommend using JQuery as much as possible.  The whole reason JQuery is popular is because it removes the inconsistencies between browsers by giving you a friendly API to write JavaScript in and not worry about browser inconsistencies.

Comment: I use JQuery, but I found that Scriptaculous is better for dragging and dropping. Thank you!